# Tensorflow nan bug with custom loss function

Tags: python, debugging, tensorflow, nan

I have some trouble debugging tensorflow code to find where the nan values come from. I have modified the [pix2pix](https://github.com/affinelayer/pix2pix-tensorflow/blob/master/pix2pix.py) code so that l1 loss now is computing the [cie94](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference) color distance between pixels:

```
 with tf.name_scope("generator_loss"):
        # predict_fake => 1
        # abs(targets - outputs) => 0
        kl = 1.0
        k1 = 0.045
        k2 = 0.015
        targetslab = rgb_to_lab(targets)
        outputslab = rgb_to_lab(outputs)

        targets_l, targets_a, targets_b = preprocess_lab(targetslab)
        outputs_l, outputs_a, outputs_b = preprocess_lab(outputslab)
        euclidean = tf.sqrt(tf.square(targets_l-outputs_l) + tf.square(targets_a-outputs_a) + tf.square(targets_b-outputs_b))
        delta_l = tf.abs(targets_l - outputs_l)
        c1 = tf.sqrt(tf.square(targets_a) + tf.square(targets_b))
        c2 = tf.sqrt(tf.square(outputs_a) + tf.square(outputs_b))
        delta_c = tf.abs(c1 - c2)
        delta_h = tf.sqrt(tf.square(euclidean) - tf.square(delta_l) - tf.square(delta_c))
        #delta_a = tf.abs(targets_a - outputs_a)
        #delta_b = tf.abs(targets_b - outputs_b)
        sl = 1.0
        sc = 1.0 + tf.multiply(k1, c1)
        sh = 1.0 + tf.multiply(k2, c1)
        gen_loss_L1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.sqrt(tf.square(tf.truediv(delta_l, tf.multiply(kl, sl))
                                                       + tf.truediv(delta_c, sc) + tf.truediv(delta_h, sh))))
        gen_loss_GAN = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.log(predict_fake + EPS))
        #gen_loss_L1 = tf.reduce_mean(tf.abs(targets - outputs))
        gen_loss = gen_loss_GAN * a.gan_weight + gen_loss_L1 * a.l1_weight
```

After changing from l1 to my custom defined loss function I keep getting nan values in my output. Everything worked fine before, so I definitely do not have nan values in targets/outputs.

Comment: Is the value you're taking the square root of in `delta_h` non-negative?

Comment: `gen_loss_L1` is calculating the square of sums where I assume you want  the sum of squares. Currently it calulates `sqrt(square(...))` which is the same as `abs(...)`.

Comment: @blender, I have added `tf.abs`, still getting nan

Comment: @interjay, thanks, fixed it

Comment: Did it solve the nan issue?

Comment: @interjay, no, it did not :/

Comment: For debugging these things sometimes it helps to set the learning rate to zero and see if the nans go away.